# Hibernate - very slow insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So I try to insert 30000 records (well the final solution would be to insert like 300000 or more records) with Hibernate.
My problem is that inserting 300 records took like 8-9 seconds which is very slow. The database is Oracle. I tried batch processing but no speed-up.

Hibernate config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">ch.nevis.estivate.util.TransactionAwareSessionContext</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Java:

```
@Transactional
public class DataGenerator {

public void generate(int nr) {
    System.out.println("START   " + new Date());
    int q = nr / 100;
    Role role = (Role) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Role.class, new Long(4));
    Client client = (Client) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Client.class, new Long(100));
    Unit unit = (Unit) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Unit.class, new Long(100));
    TemplateCollection templateCollection = (TemplateCollection) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(TemplateCollection.class, new Long(100));
    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        User user = generateUser(i, client, templateCollection);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);

        Profile profile = generateProfile(i, user, unit, client);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(profile);

        Authorization authorization = generateAuthorization(i, profile, role);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(authorization);

        if (i % q == 0) {
            System.out.println(i/q + " %     " + new Date());
        }
        if (i % 10 == 0) {  // the batch_size is 30 but I save 3 entities in one go
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("END   " + new Date());
}
```

Any hint please?
Perhaps Hibernate is not appropriate to load many records?

Thanks,
V.

------------ UPDATE -------------
Removed the custom session context class (i.e. Spring's CurrentSessionContext is in use) but no speed-up.

------------ UPDATE 2 -------------

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:/......./applicationContext-testDataGenerator.xml");
    DataGenerator dataGenerator= ctx.getBean("dataGenerator", DataGenerator.class);
    dataGenerator.generate(10000);
}
```

Comment: I think you could just store the session in a variable, right? Why do you keep calling `getCurrentSession()`?

Comment: I use LocalSessionFactoryBean and as far as I know it does the same internally.

Comment: How fast is it if you just generate the entities, but don't actually save them?

Comment: In like 10 ms  .

Comment: @Viktor I looked at that class code and it only builds a `SessionFactory`, it doesn't open a session. And the `SessionFactory` is only generated once after the properties are set.

Comment: What's the transaction management you use? Is there a transaction started? If not, chances are it's running in auto-commit, which can be slow.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I tried to save the session factory in a local variable but the result is the same.

Comment: You are using Spring why do you have your own `ch.nevis.estivate.util.TransactionAwareSessionContext`? What does it do, as it will probably break proper integration with Spirng and its tx management.

Comment: You should store the `session` in a separate variable, not the `sessionFactory`. But I presume that was what you meant.

Comment: @davida. , I use Spring, and accidentally used a custom session context class. Now I removed it and I think the default Spring's CurrentSessionContext is in use but still very slow.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I updated my question.

Comment: yes @MaartenBodewes, sorry, I stored the session.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should move the flush part outside your loop and do it just one time.

That will speed up your code.

The *batch_size* just tell Hibernate how many SQL commands to group together.

Maybe, increase the *batch_size* to speed up the insert phase.

Comment: Yes, all that  part flush() + clear() should be done just one time, so you need to move that code outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks @MarioSantini, originally there wasn't any flush() and clear() in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to speed up inserting these many records, then you should try jdbcTemplate using native queries to insert as entity conversion and query conversion will be avoided. Also do this in a batch (1000 let's say)

Comment: Thanks, that would be the next step but I don't believe that Hibernate cannot give me better performance.

Comment: Hibernate is easier to use when we're dealing with less number of records, but it will always be slower as compared to native jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate your method with `@Transactional` in order to reuse the same session along all the method flow otherwise the sessionFactory will build a new session for each call of getCurrentSession().

[**edit**]

Ensure that the generate method is called from outside.

Create a Main class, inject it an instance of DataGenerator using spring and call generate() on the injected instance. This way the spring transactionInterceptor will be applied and the session instance will be properly handled

Comment: Also Mario Santini suggestion is good, flushing the session inside the loop has no real interest except freeing some MB of ram, each flush imply a database call and cost some time

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the class header to the question but the @Transactional is there.

Comment: @Gab when doing batch inserts with hibernate you really want to flush and clear else it will simple crawl to a halt eventually due to dirty checking of entities in the first level cache.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok... I thought the dirty checking was done at flush time, so why checking many times few entities would be longer than one time many ones ?

Comment: @Victor you confirm you're calling generate() method from outside of DataGenerator aren't you ?

Comment: I call it from a main method of DataGenerator. I tried to add the @Transactional to the generate method itself but no success.

Comment: @Transactional cannot be applied from call inner to class declaring the method because it's applied by spring using an aspect (using JDK dynamic proxy). ie. The bean must have been injected by spring for the aspect to be applied

Comment: @Gab Dirty checking is done before executing a query to synchronize the memory state with the database so that the query is consistent within the current transaction. Unless the flush mode is set to manual that is.

Comment: @M. Deinum : No dirty checking is done at flush time. Appart from flush and commit, session is flushed before  *some* query execution (all sql queries and most hql update AFAIK). there is no query here :)

Comment: You don't know what happens in the `generateUser` etc. methods. And depending on the `save` it might need to issue a query to determine the id of the entity.

Comment: @Gab,  I updated the question with the 'main' method. I also tried to call the 'generate' method from another class but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

As was told previously it isn't good idea to use hibernate while saving(or even fetching) so big amount of data (if data that you handling will be very large there will be possibility to end up with OutOfMem because hibernate will store several copies of your objects in context until your session is alive and GC won't be able to clean them), but if you really need it, it will be better to use stateless session for that, it prevent you from creating of big amount of useless objects.

Also, please, be sure that you calling you `generate()` method from outside, if you  are calling it from the same class `@Transactional` won't have any effect.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have problem with the memory but the speed of the entity save. I updated the question with the 'main' method. I don't think I should put the call outside. Anyway I tried it but no difference.

Comment: Long time ago I've made some investigation and as a result sending an updates with using of simple jdbc was about 20 time faster than if using simple hibernate Session and about 3 times faster than using of StatelessSession, so my recommendation if time is very critical it is better to use jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still slow, try doing the following:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList();
List<Authorization> authorizations = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
  users.add(generateUser(i, client, templateCollection));
  profiles.add(generateProfile(i, user, unit, client));
  authorizations.add(generateAuthorization(i, profile, role));
}

users.forEach(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()::save);
profiles.forEach(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()::save);
authorizations.forEach(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()::save);
```

Not sure if it will help, but it might. I have had strange results when trying batch inserts into multiple tables (I believe in many cases batch inserts don't work when you execute inserts like you are, i.e. insert entity1 into table A, insert entity2 into table B, insert entity3 into table A, and so on..., but don't quote me on this)

Comment: I think you had such problem because you didn't set `hibernate.order_inserts` property  to `true`, in current case that won't help